# How can I change jboss logging level to show which java class I am calling?

Tags: java, logging, jboss

Is it possible to set up jboss to show which URL I called, which class I am calling, and what parameters I sent to it?

I set my class log4j.xml to TRACE, but that may not be the right .xml file to change.  It didn't seem to do anything.  Maybe I'm not looking at the right log?  I only see boot, errFile, and server.log.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enable `RequestDumper`.

In Jboss 4.x.x it can be found in the file

.../server/[YOUR_CONFIG]/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml

```
    <!-- Uncomment to enable request dumper. This Valve "logs interesting 
         contents from the specified Request (before processing) and the 
         corresponding Response (after processing). It is especially useful 
         in debugging problems related to headers and cookies."
    -->

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />
```